# Regular Expression in R (rename filename)

Tags: r, regex, extract

I have the following file names:

```
s <- c("(1) 1-B1-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", 
       "(10) 1-NEC 4-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", 
       "(11) 1-B5-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", 
       "(12) 1-B5-2_(miRNA-4_0).CEL")
```

How can I extract only the part between 1 and the number before `_` with regular expressions in R?

I want this:

`1-B1-1, 1-B5-1, 1-B5-3 etc.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub('\\S+ (.*?)_.*', '\\1', s)
[1] "1-B1-1"    "1-NEC 4-1" "1-B5-1"    "1-B5-2"  

str_extract(s, '(?<= ).*?(?=_)')
[1] "1-B1-1"    "1-NEC 4-1" "1-B5-1"    "1-B5-2"
```

Note I stole `s` from [@PaulS](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72704972/revisions)

Comment: How I can remove the 1- before the word to make my data look better? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution, based on `stringr::str_extract` and lookaround:

```r
library(stringr)

s <- c("(1) 1-B1-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", "(10) 1-NEC 4-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", "(11) 1-B5-1_(miRNA-4_0).CEL", "(12) 1-B5-2_(miRNA-4_0).CEL")

str_extract(s, "(?<=\\s).*(?=_\\()")

#> [1] "1-B1-1"    "1-NEC 4-1" "1-B5-1"    "1-B5-2"
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I expressed my question wrong, but I meant the area between 1 and before underscore. I want this: 1-B1-1, 1-B5-1, 1-B5-3 etc.

Comment: Please, @BerTu, see my updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub` twice:

`\\(\\d+\\)` match digit in parenthesis

`'_[^_]*'` match first underscore

```
trimws(gsub('\\(\\d+\\)', '', gsub('_[^_]*', '', s)))
```

```
[1] "1-B1-1"    "1-NEC 4-1" "1-B5-1"    "1-B5-2"
```